# Is it alright to split a GridSearchCV?

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, python-3.x, gridsearchcv

Is it ok to split a GridsearchCV?

At first, I would try estimators from 100-300 (100 steps) for a random forest regressor and some other parameters and after that, I would start the GridsearchCV with the same parameter and just change the estimators from 400 - 600.

Is there any aspect that would disagree with that logic?

Answer (score 3):

First my understanding of your problem. You want to find the best hyperparameters for a Random Forest.

For that, you want to first adjust n_estimators parameter and then the rest of parameters in different runs.

Before answering to your question, you will only want to do a thorough search of hyperparameters when you want to have an improvement of around 1%. So it will be a small improvement. If you want to improve your model, probably feature engineering or data engineering will give you a better improvement. Or even a different algorithm.

You can print the results of your GridsearchCV with

```py
pd.DataFrame(clf.cv_results_)
```

The answer to your question:

No you shouldn't run a GridsearchCV in different runs you have to explore the whole parameters if you want to find the global minima. A small change in one parameter can affect other. At the end you are exploring a search space.

Comment: Thank you. At first my real problem is that my gridsearch are too big. It doesnt finish before the server or kernel is dying. So therefore i thought the estimators are the only parameter i am not sure about. I want to start two gird search with the absolut same parameter but the estimators are different. I think that therefore the girdsearch is smaller an faster.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: oh, now I think I see why @CarlosMougan said no. You said

> ...start the same GridsearchCV with the same parameter and just change...

If you mean use the optimal values for all hyperparameters except `n_estimators` and now search only on that one hyperparameter, then Carlos is right, and for the right reason. Below, I interpreted your suggestion as searching over the whole space again, except with new range for `n_estimators`.

---

I don't see any reason that you can't do this. You might want to fix the cv-splits ahead of time and use the same ones for both runs of the grid search, too keep the comparisons completely fair. (In sklearn, this means passing `cv` as either one of their CV generators or as an iterable.)

This approach makes sense particularly in case

- you want to examine some results right away, so dump some smaller grid to look at while running the next grid.  (This sort of matches your case, where run times(?) are high.)
- you expected the first grid to be all, but find one hyperparameter always performs best at the edge of your grid, so now you want top extends its range.

---

Finally, please note that the number of trees in a random forest has little to do with performance; rather, more trees just stabilizes some of the randomness in the tree construction.  So generally, you want to set it "high enough," while not so high that computation is needlessly long.

Comment: Yes, I extrapolated some of the info due that the OP made this question a few hour before (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/66973/why-does-my-gridsearccv-always-break-up) and I guess that he wanted to try the strategy that exploring parameter by parameter.

Comment: @CarlosMougan I think the singular "parameter" in what I quoted also lends credence to that interpretation, though on the whole I still read it as repeating a full grid search.